Couchbase Schema Avro Issue
I wish to create a document in Couchbase, Kafka receives the message, and then SQL Server retrieves the message as a data stored in a table.
So I have my SINK in Kafka UI as the following.
{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "table.name.format": "mytopic",
    "connection.password": "******",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "usertopic",
    "schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "auto.evolve": "true",
    "connection.user": "Allen",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "name": "usertopic",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.1:1433;databaseName=pubs",
    "insert.mode": "insert",
    "pk.mode": "none"
}

While my SOURCE looks like the following.
{
    "connector.class": "com.couchbase.connect.kafka.CouchbaseSourceConnector",
    "couchbase.persistence.polling.interval": "100ms",
    "tasks.max": "2",
    "couchbase.seed.nodes": "192.168.0.1",
    "couchbase.source.handler": 
    "com.couchbase.connect.kafka.handler.source.RawJsonSourceHandler",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "couchbase.bucket": "Embedding",
    "couchbase.username": "Admin",
    "name": "usertopic_source",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "couchbase.password": "******",
    "couchbase.event.filter": "com.couchbase.connect.kafka.filter.AllPassFilter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "couchbase.topic": "usertopic"
}

When I create a document in Couchbase, the SINK fails immediately. I have made certain adjustment to the SINK, SOURCE settings, no matter what I tried, either of them would fail.
I look around and figure out that, in a sense Couchbase does not support Avro, so the SINK, SOURCE that I wrote cannot work as a pair.
Anyway, I seem to have found a solution in here, but the discussion ended up with no solution actually.
I remember that I ever saw a post in Stack addressing this issue, they come out with some JAVA code (I could not find the post anymore, and I could not understand neither), but I wonder is there a solution using plain Kafka UI setting?
EDIT:
The error log is like the following.

org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:260) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:179) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:540) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:517) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:343) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:246) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:215) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:225) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:280) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:237) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data for topic usertopic to Avro: at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:148) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$4(WorkerSinkTask.java:540) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:207) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:244) ... 14 more Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte! at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.getByteBuffer(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:641) at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:382) at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserializeWithSchemaAndVersion(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:257) at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter$Deserializer.deserialize(AvroConverter.java:199) at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:126) ... 17 more


Do you have any errors you want to share?

@siggemannen, I just edited to include the error, thank you for your time.

You probably need to use json in the sink as well, and do manual conversion in the db
